# C sockets a blocking write () call with UDP while working fine with TCP in

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, udp

I'm writing a multi service server with both UDP and TCP, I'm using writen function to send a struct between the server and the client, as said in the title, in works just fine with the TCP client while it just gets stuck in the writen function after executing this line

```
    printf ("while %lu\n",nleft);
```

Here's the code:

The server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXLINE 100


struct equation {
    float a;
    char c;
    float b;
};

struct result {
    long double res;
};

int MAX (int a,int b){
    if (a>b) return a;
    return b;
}


int readn(int fd, void *vptr, size_t n)
{
    size_t  nleft;
    ssize_t nread;
    char   *ptr;
    ptr = vptr;
    nleft = n;
    while (nleft > 0) {
        if ( (nread = read(fd, ptr, nleft)) < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                nread = 0;      /* and call read() again */
            else
                return (-1);
        } else if (nread == 0)
            break;              /* EOF */

        nleft -= nread;
        ptr += nread;
    }
    return (n - nleft);         /* return >= 0 */
}


int writen(int fd, const void *vptr, size_t n)
{
    size_t nleft;
    ssize_t nwritten;
    const char *ptr;
   // printf ("\nI'm In %lu\n",n);
    ptr = vptr;
    nleft = n;
  //  printf ("%lu NNNNN  %lu SIZE %lu \n",nleft,n,sizeof(*vptr));
    while (nleft > 0) {
        printf ("while %lu\n",nleft);
        fflush (stdout);
        if ( (nwritten = write(fd, ptr, nleft)) <= 0) {
            if (nwritten < 0 && errno == EINTR)
                nwritten = 0;   /* and call write() again */
            else
                return (-1);    /* error */
        }

        nleft -= nwritten;
        ptr += nwritten;
    }
    printf ("\n 5alawees \n");
// printf ("\n%s\n",vptr);
//    ffulsh (stdout);
    return (n);
}

void HandleClient(int comm_fd);
void Die (const char * msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int passiveUDP (short port){
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    int listen_fd;
    if ((listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        Die("Falied to create socket");
    };

    //printf ("%d" ,listen_fd);
    memset( &servaddr,0, sizeof(servaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))<0)
    {
        Die("Failed to bind socket to address");
    }
    return listen_fd;
}

int passiveTCP (short port){
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    int listen_fd;
    if ((listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        Die("Falied to create socket");
    };

    memset( &servaddr,0, sizeof(servaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))<0)
    {
        Die("Failed to bind socket to address");
    }

    if (listen(listen_fd, 10) < 0)
    {
        Die("Failed to listen on server socket");
    }
    return listen_fd;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: ./HelloITServer <port>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char str[100];
    int listen_fd, comm_fd;
    int    usock = passiveUDP (atoi (argv[1]));               /* UDP socket  */

    int    tsock = passiveTCP (atoi (argv[1]));           /* TCP master socket  */
    int    nfds;
    fd_set rfds;                 /* readable file descriptors */
    struct sockaddr_in fsin;     /* the request from address */

    nfds = MAX(tsock, usock) + 1;
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    while (1) {
        FD_SET(tsock, &rfds);
        FD_SET(usock, &rfds);
        printf ("HELLO");
        if(select(nfds, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0){
            printf("select error: %d \n",errno);
            exit (1);
        }
        if(FD_ISSET(tsock, &rfds))
        {
            /* TCP slave socket */
            //printf ("Hello TCP");
            int ssock;
            //int alen = sizeof(fsin);
            ssock = accept(tsock, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL);
            if(ssock < 0)
                Die("accept failed: jkjkjkjkjkj \n");
            HandleClient (ssock);
            close (ssock);
        }
        if(FD_ISSET(usock, &rfds))
        {
            printf ("Hello UDP\n");
            HandleClient (usock);
        }
    }

}
void HandleClient(int comm_fd)
{
    struct equation eq;
    struct result rslt;
    bzero (&eq,sizeof (eq));
    bzero (&rslt, sizeof (rslt));
    if ((readn (comm_fd, &eq, sizeof(eq))) == 0){
        Die("Failed to receive from client");
    }
  //  printf ("\n%lu  %lu\n",sizeof (struct result),sizeof (rslt));
    printf ("reciveed %f %c %f\n",eq.a,eq.c,eq.b);
    switch (eq.c) {
        case '+':
            rslt.res = eq.a+eq.b;
            break;
        case '-':
            rslt.res = eq.a-eq.b;
            break;
        case '*':
            rslt.res = eq.a*eq.b;
            break;
        case '/':
            rslt.res = eq.a/eq.b;
            break;
        case '%':
            rslt.res = (int)eq.a% (int)eq.b;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
//    printf ("\n%lu\n",sizeof(rslt));
//    printf ("\n%lu\n",sizeof(rslt));
//    printf ("\n%lu\n",sizeof(rslt));

    writen (comm_fd, &rslt, sizeof (rslt));
    //close (comm_fd);
}
```

The client (just in case u guys need it)

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct equation {
    float a;
    char c;
    float b;
};

struct result {
    long double res;
};

int readn(int fd, void *vptr, size_t n)
{
    size_t  nleft;
    ssize_t nread;
    char   *ptr;
    ptr = vptr;
    nleft = n;
    while (nleft > 0) {
        if ( (nread = read(fd, ptr, nleft)) < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                nread = 0;      /* and call read() again */
            else
                return (-1);
        } else if (nread == 0)
            break;              /* EOF */

        nleft -= nread;
        ptr += nread;
    }
    return (n - nleft);         /* return >= 0 */
}

int writen(int fd, const void *vptr, size_t n)
{
    size_t nleft;
    ssize_t nwritten;
    const char *ptr;

    ptr = vptr;
    nleft = n;
    while (nleft > 0) {
        if ( (nwritten = write(fd, ptr, nleft)) <= 0) {
            if (nwritten < 0 && errno == EINTR)
                nwritten = 0;   /* and call write() again */
            else
                return (-1);    /* error */
        }

        nleft -= nwritten;
        ptr += nwritten;
    }
    return (n);
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd,n;
    char sendline[100];
    char recvline[100];
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: ./HelloClient <server_ip> <port>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    bzero(&servaddr,sizeof servaddr);

    servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port= htons(atoi(argv[2]));

    inet_pton(AF_INET,argv[1],&(servaddr.sin_addr));

    connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
    struct result rslt;
    struct equation eq;
    //while(1)
    //{
    printf ("Accepted values by the program, from %f to %f\n", FLT_MIN, FLT_MAX);
    printf ("\n possible operations are addition, substraction, division, multiplication and modulo with operators : +,-,*,/,% respectivly\n");
    printf ("\nPlease enter the equation in this form only : \"5.0 + 2.0\" with a single space\n");
    scanf ("%f %c %f", &eq.a,&eq.c,&eq.b);
    if (eq.c!='+' && eq.c!='-' && eq.c!='*' && eq.c!='/' && eq.c!='%'){
        printf ("\n possible operations are addition, substraction, division, multiplication and modulo with operators : +,-,*,/,% respectivly\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    if (eq.c== '%'){
        if (!(eq.a == (float) ((int) eq.a) && eq.b == (float) ((int) eq.b))){
            printf ("Only integer values are accepted with the % operation, please rerun the program\n");
            exit (1);
        }
    }
    //bzero( &eq, sizeof(eq));
    bzero( &rslt, sizeof(rslt) );
    //fgets(sendline,100,stdin); /*stdin = 0 , for standard input */
    writen (sockfd, &eq, sizeof(eq));

    readn (sockfd, &rslt, sizeof(rslt));
    printf("%Lf\n thank you for using this marvelous calculator!\n",rslt.res);
    bzero( &eq, sizeof(eq));
    exit (1);
    //}
}
```

Comment: Is `errno == EINTR` every time? I don't see any other way `writen` can get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Your code misses to check the value returned by `writen()/readn()` against the error condition `-1`. Doing so might you get you enlighted.

Comment: OK I added this part
if (writen (comm_fd, &rslt, sizeof (rslt)) == -1){
        Die ("Something wrong with write");
    }
and it prints out :
Something wrong with write: Destination address required

Comment: It seems time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Note: `servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);` -->> `servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);`

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing where you are adding the IP address. There are a few more steps necessary, even if you're wanting to just use the loopback address for testing purposes.

Check out the Bind() section and see what you're missing. http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/bindman.html